# ElasticSearch multiple languages

Tags: elasticsearch, formal-languages

I am currently trying to figure out analysis schemes for my ElasticSearch cluster. I am using ES to index pdf, word, powerpoint and excel documents. I am using Apache Tika to extract the text.

My problem is that I do not know before hand what languages to expect the file contents to be. They could be written in any language.

My question is, is there a way to make ES analyze text regardless of the language? Or should I have a pre-defined field for each language with its own tokenizer, analyzer and stopwords?

Comment: Have you seen this?  http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/language-pitfalls.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at the ElasticSearch plugin [elasticsearch-mapper-attachments](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments). I used it to build document search functionality.

When it comes to supporting multiple languages, we have had the best experience with one index per language. If you can identify the language before indexing you can insert the document into the appropriate index. This makes it easier to add new languages vs. a field per language approach.

One thing to remember is the [Don't use Types for Languages](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/one-lang-docs.html) note at the bottom of one language per document page. Doing that can mess up search in a very difficult to debug way.

If you need to detect the language, there are two options mentioned at the bottom of the Pitfalls of Mixing Languages page.

Comment: Will check the mapper attachments plugin though I doubt I'll use it. Unfortunately I cannot go with an index per language approach as I already have an index per user structure. I will probably end up having a field per language.